# Typescript - get one type from generic union type of rest parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some union, generic class, and generic function

```
type SomeUnion = "first" | "second" | "third"

class SomeClass<TypeFromUnion extends SomeUnion>{}

function someFn<A extends SomeUnion, B extends SomeUnion>(a: SomeClass<A>, b:SomeClass<B>) {}
```

For call

```
someFn(new SomeClass<"first">(), new SomeClass<"second">())
```

inside the function, `a` processes as `SomeClass<"first">`, `b` as `SomeClass<"second">`. Exactly the types I need.

But I need the function to be with rest parameters. Something like:

```
function someFn<T extends SomeUnion>(...rest: SomeClass<T>[]) {}
```

With the same function call, now `rest[0]` processes as `SomeClass<"first" | "second">`. I understand why this happens, but I need the type of `rest[0]` to be processed as `SomeClass<"first">`, `rest[1]` as `SomeClass<"second">` and so on. Otherwise it breaks my next type inference. How can I achieve what I need?

The calls are expected to be like:

```
someFn(new SomeClass<"first">())
someFn(new SomeClass<"third">(), new SomeClass<"second">())
someFn(new SomeClass<"third">(), new SomeClass<"first">(), new SomeClass<"second">())
```

Comment: Consider this `function someFn(...[first, second]: [SomeClass<'first'>, SomeClass<'second'>]) { }
`

Comment: But internal implementation of function can't be sure about the order of arguments. Is this order is sealed? or you are allowed to call `third` , `second`, `first` as well ? I mean is it allowed to call any combination ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine This is not what I need. I've edited the question to clarify what function calls are expected.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine yes, it is allowed to call any combination

Comment: So, you need to create a permutation of all allowed arguments, however, if you try to get first element of `rest` it still will be a union of all of them, because first element might be either `first`, `second` or `third`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a tuple, not an array type, to separate each element of the rest generic type.
Then you could use a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays)
to map each one to the corresponding `SomeClass`

```ts
type SomeUnion = "first" | "second" | "third"

class SomeClass<TypeFromUnion extends SomeUnion>{}

function someFn<T extends [...SomeUnion[]]>(...rest: {[K in keyof T]: SomeClass<T[K]>}): typeof rest {
    return rest;
}

let vs = someFn(new SomeClass<"first">(), new SomeClass<"second">(), new SomeClass<"third">())
//  ^?let vs: [SomeClass<"first">, SomeClass<"second">, SomeClass<"third">]
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5zGMm)